# Joint values from different queries into one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 6 tables of data.
I have 2 different queries that produce a table like this

```
| PERCENTAGE | COMPANY | TYPE |
```

(the companies are always the same in all tables, the only thing that changes is the `PERCENTAGE` and the `type`). Each query gets the total_percentage of an given company for one of the 2 different types.

For example:

```
Query 1 result:

| PERCENTAGE | COMPANY | TYPE |
0.0213 | Apple | Phones
0.3452 | Microsoft | Phones

Query 2:
|PERCENTAGE | COMPANY | TYPE |
0.4243 | Apple | Computers
...
```

And the result is:

```
Result:
| SUMMED_TOTAL| COMPANY |
0.0213 + 0.4243 | Apple 
...
```

The summed percentage rows wont sum > 1, dont worry.

What i'd like to do is get the TOTAL_PERCENTAGE, from all types (all 2 queries) summed by company.

Any idea of an query? Im a begginer so it's kinda hard. You can literally use the names to do the query.

Answer (score 0):

Use `union all` and `group by`:

```
select company, type, sum(percentage)
from ((select company, type, percentage from query1) union all
      (select company, type, percentage from query2)
     ) ct
group by company, type;
```

Comment: If I read the question right, you only have to group by company, to have a single figure per company. So leave out the type field from the SELECT and GROUP BY clauses.

Comment: ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: @NotAProSad . . . Every derived table in this answer -- that needs an alias -- has one.  I don't know what that comment is referring to.